# cc1 out of memory error

Tags: linux, python, compiling, qemu, gcc

I have a machine running Xubuntu 64 bit and I'm trying to compile my pretty long C code. I am using `gcc`.

I chrooted in a raspbian stretch environment because the executable code must run on my Raspberry PI 3 model B+. To chroot I followed these instructions:

```bsh
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
sudo apt-get install qemu qemu-user qemu-user-static
sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static /mnt/usr/bin/ 
sudo chroot /mnt
```

After get inside the raspbian environment I executed:

```bsh
gcc -Os $(python3-config --cflags --ldflags) Code.c -o ExecutableCode
```

and got this output:

```
cc1: out of memory allocating 32324 bytes after a total of 543821824 bytes
```

The computational capabilities of my computer are pretty high (my PC is a workstation), therefore I do not believe that memory runs out. Does someone have ideas?

Comment: Xubuntu18.06 amd64 @K7AAY . Do you have some idea?

Comment: Xubuntu18.04, sorry for the mistake @K7AAY

Answer (score 0):

Reading the doc: `man 1 qemu-user-static` :

```
qemu-user-static(1)                                   Debian                                  qemu-user-static(1)

NAME
       qemu-user-static - QEMU User Emulator (static version)

SYNOPSIS
       qemu-user-static [options] program [program-arguments...]

DESCRIPTION
       The  qemu-user-static emulator can run binaries for other architectures but with the same operating system
       as the current one.

OPTIONS
       -h     Print this help.

       -g <port>
              Wait gdb connection to port port.

       -L <path>
              Set the elf interpreter prefix (default=/etc/qemu-binfmt/%M).

       -s <size>
              Set the stack size in bytes (default=524288).

       -d <options>
              Activate log (logfile=/tmp/qemu.log)

       -p <pagesize>
              Set the host page size to 'pagesize'.

SEE ALSO
       qemu-system(1) (in qemu-system-common package).
```

Since you didn't passed any argument to `qemu`, then it used default values for memory & cie. I guess that default values are pretty low and your compilation task exceeded it.

Running on my platform with `-h` switch gives:

```
$ sudo chroot /tmp/root/ /qemu-arm-static
usage: qemu-arm [options] program [arguments...]
Linux CPU emulator (compiled for arm emulation)

Options and associated environment variables:

Argument             Env-variable      Description
-h                                     print this help
-help                                  
-g port              QEMU_GDB          wait gdb connection to 'port'
-L path              QEMU_LD_PREFIX    set the elf interpreter prefix to 'path'
-s size              QEMU_STACK_SIZE   set the stack size to 'size' bytes
-cpu model           QEMU_CPU          select CPU (-cpu help for list)
-E var=value         QEMU_SET_ENV      sets targets environment variable (see below)
-U var               QEMU_UNSET_ENV    unsets targets environment variable (see below)
-0 argv0             QEMU_ARGV0        forces target process argv[0] to be 'argv0'
-r uname             QEMU_UNAME        set qemu uname release string to 'uname'
-B address           QEMU_GUEST_BASE   set guest_base address to 'address'
-R size              QEMU_RESERVED_VA  reserve 'size' bytes for guest virtual address space
-d item[,...]        QEMU_LOG          enable logging of specified items (use '-d help' for a list of items)
-dfilter range[,...] QEMU_DFILTER      filter logging based on address range
-D logfile           QEMU_LOG_FILENAME write logs to 'logfile' (default stderr)
-p pagesize          QEMU_PAGESIZE     set the host page size to 'pagesize'
-singlestep          QEMU_SINGLESTEP   run in singlestep mode
-strace              QEMU_STRACE       log system calls
-seed                QEMU_RAND_SEED    Seed for pseudo-random number generator
-trace               QEMU_TRACE        [[enable=]<pattern>][,events=<file>][,file=<file>]
-version             QEMU_VERSION      display version information and exit

Defaults:
QEMU_LD_PREFIX  = /etc/qemu-binfmt/arm
QEMU_STACK_SIZE = 8388608 byte

You can use -E and -U options or the QEMU_SET_ENV and
QEMU_UNSET_ENV environment variables to set and unset
environment variables for the target process.
It is possible to provide several variables by separating them
by commas in getsubopt(3) style. Additionally it is possible to
provide the -E and -U options multiple times.
The following lines are equivalent:
    -E var1=val2 -E var2=val2 -U LD_PRELOAD -U LD_DEBUG
    -E var1=val2,var2=val2 -U LD_PRELOAD,LD_DEBUG
    QEMU_SET_ENV=var1=val2,var2=val2 QEMU_UNSET_ENV=LD_PRELOAD,LD_DEBUG
Note that if you provide several changes to a single variable
the last change will stay in effect.

See <https://qemu.org/contribute/report-a-bug> for how to report bugs.
More information on the QEMU project at <https://qemu.org>.
```

maybe QEMU_STACK_SIZE is too low ...

Comment: Thanks for your time @binarym but the error is the same also increasing QEMU_STACK_SIZE. Do you know how could I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share the output of ` $(python3-config --cflags --ldflags) ̀ ?

Comment: this is what i get:  root@ubuntu:/# (python3-config --cflags --ldflags)
-I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/usr/include/python3.5m  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-RUbMX3/python3.5-3.5.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
-L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/lib -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions. @binarym